# Is there a way to opt out of Alexa rankings or prevent them from gathering data about my site?

Tags: web-crawlers, ranking, alexa

My competitor is using Alexa to see what I am doing. I need to get stop Alexa from including my sites in their rankings. How can I do so?

Is it possible to deny access to any visitor with the Alexa toolbar and deny access to Alexa bot requests?

Comment: I do not believe that you can, from a web server point of view, know if a user has the Alexa toolbar installed in a browser. I could be wrong. But I just can't see it. The Alexa toolbar is, by the way, not a bot that you can block. But the ia_archiver bot is and part 2 of the equation. You have piqued my interest! How can your competitor use Alexa to see what you are doing? Can you explain this to us so we know? There may be an answer for you, but I am not sure what you are experiencing. Can you give us a more detailed explanation?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933926/how-can-i-block-alexa-toolbar-users.

Comment: What do you mean by your competitor is seeing what you are doing?

Comment: Alexa ranks pages based on number of hits from people that have their toolbar installed. As far as I know, you can't block toolbars. The SO question you linked will only stop Alexa bots, but pretty sure those bots don't count as traffic.

How exactly does your competitor know what you're doing through Alexa? Maybe the problem can be solved some other way?

Comment: “My competitor is using Alexa to see what I am doing.” What are you doing that is somehow viewable via Alexa but not via Google or Bing or just visiting your site?

Comment: People that visit my site with proxy will simply be redirected somewhere else. Where they redirect is what I want to prevent people from seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a user has the Alexa Toolbar installed, "Alexa" appears in the user agent string of the browser.  You could deny those users access to your website using the following code in your *.htaccess* file:

```
BrowserMatchNoCase Alexa alexa_user_agent
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from env=alexa_user_agent
```

I wouldn't recommend doing this, it is going to inconvenience legitimate users to your website.   Alexa doesn't provide sensitive data to your competitors.   Only a rough estimation of how many visitors your site gets.